# Android how to see the package name of running Apps?

Tags: android, debugging, ddms

When I use emulator and install an apk file on it and run it,I can see it's package name in `Devices` window of `DDMS` perspective.But when I install that apk file on real device and connect it to PC and run that App,I can not see it's package name belove of device name in `Devices` window.I enabled `usb debugging` before.Is there any  setting that I forgot to set it?

[image]

Comment: The package name only show if you run the apk from Eclipse, not directly from real device

Comment: @ramaral say it is true.Now,is there a way to run App from eclipse on real device?

Answer (score 0):

It only shown in  emulators and probably rooted phones. 
Use USB Debugging to debug your app in a real device.
Make sure USB debugging is enabled in your phone.
If its not you can enable it by going in Settings > Developer options

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse menu choose Run->RunConfigurations
In the left pane select the project to run.
In the right pane select the `Target` tab.
Choose `Always prompt to pick device`.
Press `Apply` then `Close`.
Run the project like you do with emulator.
A window shows up, select your device.
The aplication will be instaled in the device and run automatically